# Using a MacBook Pro as an external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I would like to use my MacBook Pro (2010, with mini DisplayPort) as an external monitor for my Windows 7 PC. Before I buy an adapter, I want to know if it's even possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible. You can only use an iMac as a target display.

Comment: Any explanation on how/why this is the case? What does the iMac have that the MBP doesn't? Is there documentation to support his?

Answer (score 2):

What I would suggest trying out is using a tool called Synergy. It doesn't share monitors, but it allows you to share one pair of keyboard and mice between multiple computers. Thus allowing you to have a similar set up to an external monitor. Here's a link to their website.

http://synergy-foss.org/